# Which web browser has a logo of a molten/volcanic Earth?

Tags: browser

A while back (maybe a couple of years!) I remember some hype surrounding a soon-to-be-released web browser. All I really remember is the logo looked like a molten/volcanic Earth. It may have had a tag line along the lines of "rock solid browser".

I've done some searching and can't find any mention of it whatsoever. Does anyone remember the browser's name, and if it ever materialised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it RockMelt?

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/why-im-suspicious-of-the-facebook-rockmelt-browser/22710

"New" browsers tend to come and go like the weather.

Comment: Yes, that's the one! Looks like it's just going to be a Facebook browser, if it ever gets released. Much less interesting than I remembered ;)

Comment: Much has happened in a year or two to make it look lest interesting.

Comment: Its available now...http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/40062785/ns/technology_and_science-tech_and_gadgets/